# How can I add an unremovable postfix to an HTML input field?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I need help to do something like this

> [image]

For the prefix I used jQuery Prefix Input. It works fine, but now I want to put it after the input box, and it should be same in responsive.

htm code

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

</div>
```

css

```
.input-group-addon
{ 
  background-color:#FFF;
}
.input-group .input-group-addon + .form-control
{
   border-left:none;
}
```

here is explained for dollar sign

[here is first demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/88/)

[second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/1/)

but this not worked for me as per my requirement image shown

Comment: would you like to show what you have tried and where you were stuck?

Comment: You used bootstrap class in your html and it style changed by bootstrap. Remove bootstrap class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this -

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/kalpeshsingh/pen/LGmrPo)

Whenever you want to do such things then consider following:

1. A parent `div` with `position:relative;`
2. Your element on which you want another element (in your case, its `input` tag)
3. Element you want to put with `position:absolute;`

So, `position:absolute;` element will give you ability to move your element over another within that parent `div` and it will be always with that element due to `position:relative;` of parent.

Comment: The CodePen link is 404